# GUI for searching sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a database and lots of html. I'd like to search some plain text but i'd like to be able to click (or do something with) the results and have it show me the area it matched in the body of text. Is there any gui that lets me do that? If not than how do i execute a command with sqlite3.exe and have it dump the results to out.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Firefox you could try the [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/).